# How to extend existing KeySelector

Tags: c#, expression-trees

```
public class Address 
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    public Address Address1 { get; set; }
    public Address Address2 { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultAddressSortingSpecification<TEntity>
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<TEntity, Address>> _keySelector;

    public DefaultAddressSortingSpecification(Expression<Func<TEntity, Address>> keySelector)
    {
        _keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> OrderingEntitiesFrom(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
    {
        //order by city
        //order by street
    }
}

usage: 

var s1 = new DefaultAddressSortingSpecification<User>(user => user.Address1);
var s2 = new DefaultAddressSortingSpecification<User>(user => user.Address2);
```

I would like to have universal AddressSortingSpecification. _keySelector points to Address entity. How to add City or Street to it?

Normally I can write something like this: user.Address1.City

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want when you say you _"want to add city or street to it"_? It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: _keySelector selects user.Address1 property. In OrderingEntitiesFrom method I want to make it select user.Address1.City property (and user.Address1.Street). Note that this method does not know where Address entity pointed by _keySelector is (and which address it is).

Comment: Instead of passing the address selector to the constructor, why not just pass two selectors, one for City and one for Street?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to know how to create expressions to access the `City` and `Street` properties of an `Address` when given an expression which only references an `Address`. Here's how I would do it:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> OrderingEntitiesFrom(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
{
    var parameter = _keySelector.Parameters.Single();

    var address = _keySelector.Body;

    var citySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, string>>(Expression.Property(address, "City"), parameter);
    var streetSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, string>>(Expression.Property(address, "Street"), parameter);

    return query.OrderBy(citySelector).ThenBy(streetSelector);
}
```

Comment: why the invoke? `var parameter = _keyselector.Parameters.Single();' and 'var address = _keyselector.Body;' But anyways, for me is still unclear what the OP wants...

Comment: Thanks @MBoros, I wasn't thinking straight, and definitively not in linq-to-sql terms!

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie If city was an entity, how would I access City.Name? I'm getting exception: Address does not contain definition of Name.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to nest two calls to `Expression.Property`: `Expression.Property(Expression.Property(address, "City"), "Name")`.